# Bootstrap forms, on clicking the label name it goes to the input field

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to add a content-editable fields to the label of the bootstrap form, but as soon as I click to edit the label name the cursor moves to the input field.

Please help me in that, I have just added `contenteditable = "true"` to the label field.

Thanks!!

Gaurav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `for` of your labels :

```
<label for="name">Name</label><input name="name"/>
```

=>

```
<label>Name</label><input name="name"/>
```

Comment: I am also using the jquery validator plugin and it validates the field specified in the for.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck then

Comment: you marked the other as the answer tho ... nevermind anyway, glad it works xD

Comment: You can only mark one by the way – if the answers are similar I usually pick the person with the lowest reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, not sure why you'd want this behaviour, but I assume you have good reason!

The 'for' attribute on the label controls this behaviour, simply remove it from the label.

Comment: I am also using the jquery validator plugin and it validates the field specified in the for.